# Is there a way to style an independent TableView column?

Tags: css, tableview, javafx

I can use the CSS to style cells, but what if I want a different style (like using a different text color) for just one column.

Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to use [TableColumn#setCellFactory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) to customize cell item rendering.
For example, datamodel with like this [Person class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJADAHAH):

```
// init code vs..
TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(getCustomCellFactory("green"));

TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
lastNameCol.setCellFactory(getCustomCellFactory("red"));

table.setItems(data);
table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

// scene create code vs..
```

and the common `getCustomCellFactory()` method:

```
private Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> getCustomCellFactory(final String color) {
        return new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> param) {
                TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(final String item, boolean empty) {
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item);
                            setStyle("-fx-text-fill: " + color + ";");
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Still, a simple CSS-based solution would be great though, just adding an ID field to a TableColumn object that you can use to style it