# JavaFX: Give Line Chart Series of multiple tables different colors

Tags: java, javafx, linechart, javafx-css

I have an application that displays several Line Charts with several Series like this:

[image]

I'd like to change the color of each Series but haven't found a way to achieve this. The only thing I found is how to change the default colors but that doesn't solve my problem.

Is there really now way to achieve individual colors for chart series?

Comment: Set the color [via CSS](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#linechart). To target a specific chart, give the chart an ID.

Comment: Depends on the version of JavaFX, the preferable way is to use CSS

Comment: @Slaw Thank you. This looks promising and I already have a CSS file but I'm not sure how to implement/use these style classes to get what I want.
`chart-series-line series<i> default-color<j>` seems to only change what series gets what default color. This would lead to the first series of each Line Chart still getting the same color, would it not?

Comment: Oracle have an [old tutorial for styling charts](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm).  It might be a bit out of date, but still mostly relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#linechart) says the following for `LineChart`:

> | Style class | Comments | Properties |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `"chart-series-line series<i> default-color<j>"` | Where `<i>` is the index of the series and `<j>` is the series’ color index | `Node` |
> | `"chart-line-symbol series<i> data<j> default-color<k>"` | Where `<i>` is the index of the series, `<j>` is the index of the data within the series, and `<k>` is the series’ color index | `Node` |
> | `"chart-line-symbol series<i> default-color<j>"` | Where `<i>` is the index of the series and `<j>` is the series’ color index | `LegendItem` |

<sup>***Note:** Although the line is only documented as a `Node`, by default it is actually a `javafx.scene.shape.Path`.*</sup>

If you want to target a specific series' line, use `.chart-series-line.series<i>`, where `<i>` is replaced with the index of the series in the chart's data. And if you want to give a series of a *specific chart* a certain color, then simply give the chart an ID and use that in the CSS selector.

Here's an example. It uses so-called looked-up colors, which makes the CSS a little more scalable and organized. Also, they can have their values changed via the `setStyle` method in code, allowing you to dynamically change the color programmatically. Another approach for that is to use a "data URL", showcased in [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74074598/1155209).

**style.css**:

```css
/*
 * The '-fx-stroke' is used to set the color of the line. The line is
 * targeted by the '.chart-series-line.series<i>' selectors.
 *
 * The '-fx-background-color' is used to set the color of the legend
 * symbol so it matches the line. This would also color the symbols
 * on the line if they were shown. These symbol nodes are targeted
 * by the '.chart-line-symbol.series<i>' selectors.
 *
 * Both the '-fx-series0-color' and '-fx-series1-color' "properties"
 * are looked-up colors. You can change the value of a looked-up color
 * in code by calling 'setStyle(...)' on the appropriate node.
 */

 #firstChart {
    -fx-series0-color: magenta;
    -fx-series1-color: dodgerblue;
 }

#secondChart {
    -fx-series0-color: red;
    -fx-series1-color: black;
}

#firstChart .chart-series-line.series0,
#firstChart .chart-line-symbol.series0 {
    -fx-stroke: -fx-series0-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-series0-color;
}

#firstChart .chart-series-line.series1,
#firstChart .chart-line-symbol.series1 {
    -fx-stroke: -fx-series1-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-series1-color;
}

#secondChart .chart-series-line.series0,
#secondChart .chart-line-symbol.series0 {
    -fx-stroke: -fx-series0-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-series0-color;
}

#secondChart .chart-series-line.series1,
#secondChart .chart-line-symbol.series1 {
    -fx-stroke: -fx-series1-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-series1-color;
}
```

**Main.java**:

```java
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var chart1 = createLineChart("Chart 1");
        chart1.setId("firstChart");
        chart1.getData().add(createSeries("f(x) = x", x -> x));
        chart1.getData().add(createSeries("f(x) = 2x", x -> 2 * x));

        /*
         * Uncomment the line of code below to demonstrate dynamically changing
         * the value of a looked-up color.
         */
        // chart1.setStyle("-fx-series0-color: goldenrod;");

        var chart2 = createLineChart("Chart 2");
        chart2.setId("secondChart");
        chart2.getData().add(createSeries("f(x) = x^2", x -> x * x));
        chart2.getData().add(createSeries("f(x) = x^3", x -> x * x * x));

        var root = new VBox(10, chart1, chart2);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 720));
        primaryStage.getScene()
                .getStylesheets()
                .add(Main.class.getResource("/style.css").toString());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private LineChart<Number, Number> createLineChart(String title) {
        var chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        chart.setTitle(title);
        chart.getXAxis().setLabel("x");
        chart.getYAxis().setLabel("f(x)");
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        return chart;
    }

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> createSeries(
            String name, 
            UnaryOperator<Double> func) {
        var series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName(name);

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, func.apply((double) x)));
        }

        return series;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, if you need to dynamically set the colors in code, you can use a CSS data url, kind of like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74074598/1155209).

Comment: @jewelsea Nice! Didn't know that was possible. I've always implemented that by using looked-up colors. I've edited my answer to show that approach and to link to your answer for the data URL approach.

Comment: Yeah the data urls work well with [string formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) for dynamically setting values in css when looked up colors aren’t enough.  It will work well with [string templates](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430) when that feature is released.  IDEs like idea can recognize the language type of multi-line strings used in a data url and apply css specific formatting, parsing and highlighting.