# JavaFX 8 getting the effective CSS for a widget

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I was working on styling JavaFX with CSS and realized that there is no apparent way of understanding what CSS properties are affecting the view of a GUI widget at any given time. This is the equivalent of selecting a gui widget with the firefox web developer tools> inspector and seeing the selector referring to the widget together with the properties that are working to style the element. The strange thing was that even though there is a central css style applied (e.g. Modena css) when I use the built in getStyle() method on any Node, I get an empty String.

So, the question is how will I be able to understand what properties are applicable to style a specific element. Say a .table-cell or a .table-row-cell and what properties come from a parent of that element. Say a .table-view.

For example, to control the cell font:
[Is there a way to style an independent TableView column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694792/is-there-a-way-to-style-an-independent-tableview-column])
Excellent article, but my point is imagine having tens of cascading properties scattered around in your code. Some, inline using Java code, that affect presentation in runtime and others in .css files. How will one be able to find their way around this situation?

NOTE: This is not a generic question. I am literally trying to find a way to see the whole number of properties for any GUI element in a compact way. 
A way that would contain all the applicable properties:
- those are inherited
- those that come from the central CSS file (like modena)
 
- those that come from local CSS files in my application
 
- those that come from code and ideally 
- those that are not set yet 
e.g. setStyle("{-fx-font-size:16px;}")

COMMENT: Currently, I am wading through a host of per GUI element StackOverflow articles to find a specialized solution for controlling a specific CSS property. This process kind of defeats the purpose for CSS. It is way easier and better to organize your presentation code in good old-fashioned classes and do the whole styling using Java code. Isn't it?

Comment: I wonder how you want to accomplish the *"those that are not set yet"* part. Usually it's pretty hard to see the effects of code that has not yet been executed...

Comment: What I meant was that every JavaFX GUI widget has a predefined limited set of properties that can be set using either Java code or CSS. All the other properties, are not affecting the widget at all. The problem is that (to my knowledge) there is no way to find which those properties are before setting them. In addition to that, the CSS parser does not complain when you set the wrong property, it just ignores it. I understand that there is the JavaFX specification but it's not so easy to search when changing a massive amount of properties for different widgets.

Comment: Also the Java affected properties can be found quite easily from the Javadoc, or simply by perusing the available methods for an object, this is not possible for the CSS controlled ones, though. The same is true for CSS in HTML, that s why the Firefox web development tools (and other similar tools) proved to be so useful! If anyone believes that these comments are essential to understanding the question above, please ask me to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer

To visualize the Java code controlled properties together with the CSS controlled ones in a live scene (which is the exact equivalent to the Firefox web development tools) there is a tool called 
**Scenic View**.
 It can be found here:
http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/

The tool's help section is here:
http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/help/

The JavaFX CSS reference guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html